# Mailgun Deliverability Issues

Tags: mailgun

I'm going to be migrating a lot of customers off Mandrill soon and Mailgun sounded pretty good so I moved one small client over but already have a bounce to a valid address:

Server response: 554 554 BigPond Inbound Connection refused. IB112

This looks to me like the customer's email host / ISP is refusing to accept messages from a Mailgun IP.

This is very worrying as one of their competitors has also claimed they worst deliverability of the big players in this space.

Any past and present Mailgun users have issues such as this? (This was very very rare with mandrill). Would hate to migrate 20+ customers to a platform that has really bad deliverability as these are ecommerce related emails so very important that they are delivered.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing further delivery issues I contacted them and they apparently "moved me to a different node". Still experienced delivery issues.

Ended up moving to postmark and it's been flawless. Highly recommend postmark if you are sending transactional emails only and no bulk mail.